# Adding dots (Like the ones in UIPageViewController) to a SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, skscene

How do I add the dots like those that are in the `UIPageViewController` to my game? I want to tell it how many dots there are and whether to choose the first, second or third dot for example.

(By choosing I mean to make it more visible than the others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UIPageControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol) as a ready made solution to this.

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl()
self.view.addSubview(self.pageControl)
self.pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    self.pageControl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 43),
    self.pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -33)
])
```

Then you can control number of its dots:

```
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfTotalDots
```

And set which one is selected:

```
self.pageControl.currentPage = selectedDot
```

Comment: This works, thanks!
by the way, do you know if there is a way to make all previous pages selected instead of the current one?

Comment: @MeshalM I believe you would have to implement your own component, that is not supported by the `UIPageControl`